# Accessing Storage From Orchestrated Espresso Test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, android-storage

I have a test apk being built, and I'd like that test apk to be able to read some configuration values from an external file, rather than having to compile that configuration into the apk file.

I have a method in an Espresso `TestRule` that attempts to do this, but I appear to be being stymied by the external storage permission changes. The following code results in a permissions error on SDK 28 and 29, and on SDK 30 I get a security exception

> Permission android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE requested by $myPackageNameHere is not a changeable permission type

```kotlin
val instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
val packageName =  instrumentation.context.packageName
   with(instrumentation.uiAutomation) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
         grantRuntimePermission(packageName, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
      }
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
         grantRuntimePermission(packageName, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
         grantRuntimePermission(packageName, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
      }

   }

val dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
val configFile = File(dir, "test-config.json")

FileInputStream(configFile).use {
   config = json.decodeFromStream(it)
}
```

I've tried getting the external files directory for my test's context, but it's *always* null (I've tried calling it multiple times, it doesn't help, still null. And I've checked the mounted state, and the external storage is mounted.

```kotlin
instrumentation.context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
val dir = instrumentation.context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

I can get the external files directory of the target context:

```kotlin
instrumentation.targetContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)
val dir = instrumentation.targetContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

However I'm also using the orchestrator with `clearPackageData: true`, so this directory gets wiped, and it appears to happen before my test gets instantiated. So the file doesn't exist - not that I'd be able to read it from my test anyway!

I noticed this section of the data storage use-cases here, which should allow opting out for the test - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-tests - but I'm not sure how to get this passed via the test runner. It suggests using it to write test data, but we have test-services to handle that during orchestration - I need to *read* data, not *write* data. Also, it looks like it impacts the app that's being tested too, and it implies that this is why  `getExternalFilesDir(null)` on my test context return null.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Or am I stuck compiling the config file into the test apk and reading it like this:

```kotlin
this::class.java.classLoader?.getResource("test-config.json")?.openStream()?.use {
   config = json.decodeFromStream(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, it seems not to be possible to request **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** via `grantRuntimePermission()`. The only solution I found to grant this permission **for testing** is via shell command.

Create your own Rule:

```
public class GrantManageStoragePermissionRule implements TestRule {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Statement apply(@NonNull Statement base, @NonNull Description description) {
        return new RequestManageStoragePermStatement(base);
    }

    private static class RequestManageStoragePermStatement extends Statement {

        private final Statement base;

        public RequestManageStoragePermStatement(Statement base) {
            this.base = base;
        }

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            ParcelFileDescriptor desc = getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "appops set --uid "+ BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+" MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow");
            desc.close();
            base.evaluate();
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
@Rule
public GrantManageStoragePermissionRule manageStoragePermRule = new GrantManageStoragePermissionRule();
```

But I doubt that this should be the solution for your use case. Granting such a heavy permission just for testing may cause unwanted side effects in other tests.